# LIve OS updation on pendrive

Tags: 18.04, live-usb, iso, persistence

i have made pendrive as bootable drive without presistant mode.Now i made changes in the iso image and i have to update  my pendrive without erasing the contents on the drive.

Are there any procedure to update my pendrive with new image.

Comment: You must re-make a new LiveUSB using the new .iso image. There is no "update."

Comment: What you can do is copy  files or even the whole home directory alias backup into another drive. But after that you will have to reinstall programs that you have installed, because as already said, you have to make a fresh installation of a [persistent live system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) or [installed system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) (installed like into an internal drive but into a pendrive).

Comment: How did you make this pendrive? What tool did you use, Rufus, UNetbootin, Universal, SDC, or mkusb? Do you want a drive that saves data, settings and downloaded programs or just a Live drive that starts fresh every boot?

Comment: I used rufus  to make the bootable pendrive. We have custom usb pendrive,After writing iso in to drive we are making it as a read-only drive and we are giving it our customers. if customers wants to add any application now he is unable to install and use as it is read-only drive. when customer contacts us we are repacking iso with the application. to update new ISO we have make drive read-write and write. customers are at remote location  and iam looking for mechanism like patching current iso with new iso on device.

Answer (score 0):

There is no procedure to change the contents of a LiveUSB since the USB flash memory drive holds a compressed image to boot and run Ubuntu from, instead of a traditional directory structure with uncompressed files.  As suggested above, copy what you want to preserve, make a new LiveUSB with persistence, and copy the preserved files back onto the LiveUSB.